# Unable to install seeker

Tags: php, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install seeker but when I do `sudo ./install.sh`, this is the error I get everytime:

```
[!] Installing Dependencies...
./install.sh: line 8: Python3 - Failed!: command not found
PHP - Failed!
Requests - Failed!
Packaging - Failed!
```

Comment: Please provide more details, like OS, versions and files you use. List them all here

Answer (score 0):

use the command "apt-get update"
before installing seeker

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try using it anyway. The error is because you already have those installed. I did it and worked perfect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).